# How must I configure Debian or Ubuntu to ensure there's a chain of trust from TPM to Login?

Tags: linux, systemd, luks, tpm

TPMs are supposed to solve a chicken and egg problem of where to store unencrypted disk encryption keys such that someone can't simply pop another hard drive in the machine, boot a different OS and read the keys right off the disk / flash / BIOS / ...

AFAIK TPMs basically do this by checking what software booted and, if that software doesn't match a preset hash, it will remain locked and refuse to give out the disk encryption keys.

I've read numerous articles pointing to the fact that systemd can help embed my LUKS keys in a TPM with [systemd-cryptenroll](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-cryptenroll.html#:%7E:text=systemd%2Dcryptenroll%20is%20a%20tool,unlock%20the%20volume%20during%20boot.).  But these only speak of embedding the key in the TPM, and not preventing attackers reading those keys.

Where I'm stuck is figuring out how to ensure there's a solid chain of trust from BIOS firmware to login ensuring that if the OS is tampered with it will either not boot, or the TPM will refuse to hand over the encryption key.

For example there's not much use in encrypting my hard drive if someone at the terminal could simply press <kbd>E</kbd> at the grub prompt and boot linux with `init=/bin/bash` to give themselves a root login without needing a password.  Encryption would be utterly pointless in that situation.

I'm stuck on two fairly specific points:

- What does a typical systemd based distribution (Debian or Ubuntu) do to lock the TPM in the first place. What files does this protect from tampering?
- What other things in the boot sequence must I harden from tampering?

  - eg: grub EFI binary, grub.cfg in EFI, grub passwordles editing boot entries, initramfs, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where I'm stuck is figuring out how to ensure there's a solid chain of trust from BIOS firmware to login ensuring that if the OS is tampered with it will either not boot, or the TPM will refuse to hand over the encryption key.

That's built into the process; it's the `--tpm-pcrs=` option that you give to systemd-cryptenroll.

The TPM keeps an in-memory "event log" of various events provided to it by system firmware, by the bootloader, and occassionally by the OS. Each event "measures" some part of the system – e.g. the firmware will log a hash of the grubx64.efi executable as it is loaded; GRUB will log every command and (probably?) log a hash of the kernel image being executed; the kernel will log a hash of the initrd and a hash of the command line – and each event "extends" a hash chain that's also stored in the TPM's memory.

The destination of all those measurements is a set of PCRs, "platform configuration registers", each of which holds a SHA hash. Each event extends one of the PCRs using the formula:

```
new_value = H(old_value || event_data_hash)
```

so that the final hash in the PCR authenticates the entire event chain for that PCR, exactly like how a single Git commit hash authenticates the entire history of commits leading up to it. (Although there is only one event log, each event only updates a single PCR, so each of the PCRs acts as an independent hash chain.)

On their own, the PCRs do absolutely nothing, but the "seal" operation can be used to specify a *policy* that may require specific PCRs to have specific values; if the policy is not met, the TPM will refuse to unseal the data.

So whenever `systemd-cryptenroll` asks the TPM to seal (encrypt) the LUKS volume key, it includes a policy based on whatever `--tpm-pcrs=` you have specified. What exactly is being secured depends on which PCRs you select.

For example, PCR[4] will contain firmware-generated events that measure every .efi executable that's being run. (This might include the Linux kernel if it's being run as an "EFI stub" with its own embedded bootloader.) This can get annoying as the hashes will change on every upgrade, so Windows with BitLocker often ties the tamper protection to Secure Boot – it binds to PCR[7] which instead contains events for the *certificates* that were used to sign the executables; anything signed by Microsoft's "official Windows first-party certificate" will pass.

Then, if you also wanted to measure the initramfs, with modern (5.17+) Linux kernels you would include PCR[9] in the policy. For the kernel cmdline, systemd-boot would update PCR[8]. (I'm not sure what GRUB uses or when.) Recently systemd developers have put more emphasis on the "Unified Kernel Images" that contain the kernel and the initramfs and the command line bundled together; the entire bundle would be authenticated as a single .efi binary.

(I have an [old project](https://github.com/grawity/tpm_futurepcr/) that's able to dump the event log in text format, in addition to its regular functions.)

---

Specifically for Linux there's a non-authoritative guide to which PCR indexes are used for which purposes [here](https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/linux_tpm_pcr_registry/).

On Ubuntu, the package [tpm2-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/tpm2-tools) includes the command `tpm2_eventlog` which can be used to read the TPM's event log via the kernel:

```bash
tpm2_eventlog /sys/kernel/security/tpm0/binary_bios_measurements
```

This can help determine exactly what content was used to generate the PCR values and therefore which files and settings are effectively protected from tampering.