# password to linux changed after deleting/manipulation with ssh

Tags: hostname, ssh-agent, github, system-recovery, password-store

Unfortunatelly I made mistake somewhere but can't get where. I had issues with ssh and github, tried different things and they didn't work. Later I decided .. i think.. moved file i balieve it was home/username/known.hosts or smth like that. Additonally I deleted everything from folder, where id_25519 and id_25519.pub files (maybe they are related to github, i don't know). And somewhere in between or afteer all. I could not provide my password in terminal. I 200% sure it's correct, no caps/num/ other things used. and now i can't log in to my linux mint cinamon 20. I will really appreciate any help how can I recover my laptop. It starts, but requires pass. And I can't understad how coudl it change ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely modifying anything in your home directory will have reset your password. On most distributions it's stored in `/etc/shadow` by default.

To get to a recovery console, the most easy thing to try is to change the `init` kernel parameter on boot.

Assuming you are booting with grub:

- switch on your computer
- At the boot menu press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot entry
- You might be asked for your grub password if you have one set
- Modify the line starting `linux` to add `init=/bin/bash` at the end
- Press <kbd>f10</kbd> to boot

This should give you a root command line with `/` mounted readonly.  To make it read-write remount it:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

You should be able to reset your password with:

```
passwd <username>
```

And finally reboot with:

```
 reboot
```

Comment: Thanks. will check this in several hours

Comment: how can I pay off? It helped but I would never do this by my own. Do you have buymeacoffee account? or patreon or anything)?

Comment: @MaksChornyi check my profile links ;-) glad it helped